# Setting up a mercurial server on media temple grid

Tags: mercurial, mediatemple

I have successfully installed mercurial on media temple grid server. But I can not find any information about setting up a mercurial server on grid so I can push/pull multiple repositories on my grid server.

How can I setup a mercurial server with multiple repositories on media temple grid server?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can setup Mercurial on all hosts using the [instructions in the wiki](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/PublishingRepositories#hgweb). The `hgweb.cgi` script allows you to push and pull to multiple repositories. You can see it in action at https://www.mercurial-scm.org/repo/hg.